# In C++, what is the keyword used to refer to a 32-bit floating point value?

Tags: c++, floating-point, 32-bit, keyword

In C++, what is the keyword used to refer to a 32-bit floating point value?:

Comment: Drop "ing" from your question.  I love a good puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

`float`

This is almost always a 32b IEEE floating point

Comment: Interesting. Almost always? Can it really be something other than 32 bits?

Comment: @Doug T: Yes it can be the same size as the double.

Comment: @Doug it can be non IEEE. IIRC, some CRAY machines have 64b floats (and 128b doubles)

Comment: @Kitsune, @Martin, @Doug: `float` can be just about anything in C or C++, but realistically it is IEEE-754 `binary32` on basically all non-embedded/non-exotic platforms.  There were an enormous number of floating-point formats in the days before IEEE-754 (see http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/cp0201.htm for some examples), and the C language committee made a conscious decision not to exclude legacy hardware by requiring IEEE-754 conformance (it is, however, recommended practice)

Comment: Here "legacy hardware" includes IBM mainframes, which shouldn't be excluded from any language spec.

Comment: I've used one PC C compiler (`lcc`?) that made `float` the same as `double`.

Comment: @Bo Persson: the default floating-point format on IBM mainframes in 64-bit mode is IEEE-754, is it not?  I believe the hexadecimal support is mainly provided for legacy compatibility.

Comment: Doesn't x87 have a BCD floating point mode? Can c access it and store it in floats?

Answer (score 3):

float

here's an example:

```
float var = 0.0f;
```

Notice the lowercase f to indicate the literal should be interpreted as a 32-bit floating point number.

Answer (score 1):

```
float - 32 bits
double - 64 bits
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the IEEE-754 32-bit floating point is represented by the keyword `float`.

```
float myVar = 0.8;
myVar = 4.0f;
```

For 64-bit floating point values, there's `double`:

```
double myVar = 0.8;
myVar = 4.0f;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the completely useless answer, buddy.